# Cannot connect HTC 10 to Windows 10 USB device malfunctioned

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, phone

When I connect my HTC 10 to my Windows 10 laptop, I get the error: "The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it". It connects to my Windows 10 desktop fine.

I can connect my iPad, iPhone, and HTC EVO Shift to the laptop on any port.

In device manager I see error on: Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed). If I look at details it says, Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems (Code 43).

I have searched the web and "think" I've tried everything... except I do NOT have a Generic USB Hub in device manager to update. What I've done is:

- Shut down, pulled battery, let sit
- Tried multiple cables and all USB ports
- Updated driver
- Uninstalled and reinstalled driver
- Updated essentially everything under Universal Serial Bus Controllers
- Unchecked Allow this computer to turn off device to save power on all hubs
- Changed the USB Selective Suspend Settings
- Ran the hardware troubleshooter
- Added EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled to the registry
- Disabled fast boot in power options
- Copied usf.inf stuff from windows\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\usb.inf_
- Updated BIOS
- Installed the latest HTC drivers
- Installed HTC Sync Manager (which is discontinued)
- Swore at Microsoft and HTC

Anyone have anything else to try?

Comment: HTC 10 has USB Type-C connector. Are you sure you are using right cable to connect?

Comment: Did you try a USB hub between your laptop and HTC 10?

Comment: I've used both a cable with C connector as well as with a mini to C converter... remember, this works on my desktop.  Tried the hub but no change.

Comment: Which hub? Model, picture? Does the hub function with other devices? Did you try any other hub? Which mini-to-c converter? Does the mini-to-c cable arrangement work with other PCs? You are having a specific problem with your laptop, please supply specific details. I suspect your HTC10 phone uses QC charger handshake that confuses your particular laptop.

Comment: Belkin 4 port hub.  Yes, hub works with other devices.  However, Mini-to-C or straight C cable does not work in any PC now.  I'm getting the same error on my Desktop as I did on the Laptop.  So, I suspect something is failing in my phone now.